# Reading a YAML file from a Maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, yaml

I have a scenario where I have one `api-rest.yml` file inside one of the Maven dependencies of my Spring project.
This dependency doesn't have any class in it, only static `.md` and `.yml` files.
Is there a way I can read this `.yml` file?
I've already tried the following approaches:

1. `final ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("api-rest.yml");`
2. ```java
    final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    final ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader);
        Resource[] resources = new Resource[0];
        try {
            resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:/**/rest/*.yml");
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   ```

Comment: there is a typo on my question, I meant `resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:/**/rest/*.yml");`

Comment: You can edit your question via the _Edit_ link under its tags.

Comment: What is the result of your approach? Maven dependencies are JARs, WARs, ... and the like which are in fact ZIPs. So, usually you have to extract files therein to be able to access them.

Comment: Approach (2) should work, as long as the path is correct.